# Set initial value in a form in Django

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I have a model in my application:

models.py:

```
class bdAccesorios(models.Model):
    fdClienteAcc=models.CharField(max_length=35)
    fdProveedorAcc=models.CharField(max_length=60)
    fdSkuAcc=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    fdNombreAcc=models.CharField(max_length=60)
    fdCostoAcc=models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    fdUnidadAcc=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    fdExistenciaAcc=models.IntegerField()
    fdAuxAcc=models.CharField(max_length=60, default="0")
```

Then, I have a form to add new entries to the model

```
class fmAccesorios(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=bdAccesorios
        fields='__all__'
```

What I can't accomplish is that the form starts with an initial value, so far what I have done in my views is this, but the field shows blank

views.py

```
def vwCrearAccesorio(request):
    vrCrearAcc=fmAccesorios(initial={'fdClienteAcc':"foo"}) ###Here is the problem ###
    if request.method == "POST":
        vrCrearAcc=fmAccesorios(request.POST)
        if vrCrearAcc.is_valid():
            vrCrearAcc.save()
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            vrCrearAcc=fmAccesorios()
    return render(request,"MyApp/CrearAccesorio.html",{
        "dtCrearAcc":vrCrearAcc
    })
```

MORE INFO:

I know that I can use the following code in my form to set initial values

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(fmAccesorios, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['fdClienteAcc'].disabled = True
    self.fields['fdClienteAcc'].initial = "foo"
```

But I can't use that, because I need the variable "foo" to change dynamically, my ultimate goal is to use
the request.user.username variable and then use that variable to get another value from another model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view you have to pass the current **instance** you need to the form like this:

```
def vwCrearAccesorio(request):
    vrCrearAcc=fmAccesorios(initial={'fdClienteAcc':"foo"}) # this will not be used because you reassign `vrCrearAcc` later
    if request.method == "POST":
        vrCrearAcc=fmAccesorios(request.POST, initial={'fdClienteAcc':"foo"}) # pass it here
        if vrCrearAcc.is_valid():
            vrCrearAcc.save()
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            vrCrearAcc=fmAccesorios(initial={'fdClienteAcc':"foo"}) # and here
    return render(request,"MyApp/CrearAccesorio.html",{
        "dtCrearAcc":vrCrearAcc
    })
```